# swift iterating webfolder for putting filenames in a array

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I want to put the filenames of a web folder "mywwwaddress" into an array
but the println gives me an empty array: []

```
func files(){
    var urls : [NSURL] = []
    let dirUrl = NSURL(string: "mywwwadres")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator? = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(dirUrl!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)

    while let url = enumerator?.nextObject() as! NSURL? {
        urls.append(url)
    }

    println(urls)
}
```

Comment: In your question, the directory is named "mywwwaddress", whereas in your code, you're using "mywwwadres" (single `d` and `s`). Did you double-check whether you've spelled the directory name correctly?

Comment: thank you Frank,it is another address which I wouldn't show on this forum

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code with a URL of a directory on my local file system, it works OK for me, so you may want to put more error handling in to see if there's a problem reaching the URL you're using.

Also, since `NSEnumerator` conforms to `SequenceType`, you can use `for...in` or other sequence-processing operations like `map` on it instead, which can simplify the code a little.

Here's a version with more error handling to try:

```
func files() {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let url = NSURL(string: "mywwwadres")
    assert(url != nil, "Invalid URL")

    let enumerator = url.flatMap { fileManager.enumeratorAtURL($0,
                        includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                        options: nil)
        { url, error in
            println("error with url \(url): \(error)")
            return true  // true to keep going
        }
    }
    assert(enumerator != nil, "Failed to create enumerator")

    let urls = enumerator.map { enumerator in
        map(enumerator) { url in
            url as! NSURL
        }
    }

    println(urls ?? [])
}
```

Comment: at url: "http://ios.xxx.nl/img" I get the error message:   error with url nil: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x7fd243e34a30 {NSURL=http://ios.xxxx.nl/img, NSFilePath=/img, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd243e34990 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
[]

Comment: Right so your URL is bad.  Try going to it in a web browser.

Comment: in de webbrowser II can't open "ios.xxx.nl/img" and get a 403 forbidden access is denied, but I can open an image at " ios.xxx.nl/img/flower.jpg" that the reason I want enumerate the folder to read the images inside the web folder is there another way with swift code?

Comment: probably not - this isn't really a swift problem, fundamentally the web server isn't giving you permission to get the directory listing I'm afraid